# Como exportar uma classe em Node?

Tags: node.js

`insira o código aqui`Versão do Node 10.5.3
Estou tentando exportar uma classe, para usa-lá em outro arquivo. Já vi vários exemplos na internet e nenhum deles me ajudou.

Logo abaixo tem a classe que eu quero exportar.

```js
class Retangulo {
    constructor(altura, largura) {
      this.altura = altura; this.largura = largura;
    }

    get area() {
        return this.calculaArea()  
    }  

    calculaArea() {  
        return this.altura * this.largura;  
    }
} 

module.exports = Retangulo;
```

E o arquivo aonde estou tentando usar a classe Retangulo

```
const Retangulo =  require('./teste.js');
var a =  new Retangulo(10,10)
console.log(a.area);
```

Dá pra consertar esse erro usando o "module.exports = new Retangulo();", só que assim ele retorna um objeto já instanciado, e eu quero instanciálo direto no arquivo teste1.js. Eu estou usando o consign para carregar as minhas rotas.

Esse código está no meu arquivo de server.js

```
consign().include('models').into(app);
```

Alguem pode me ajudar com isso. Caso não esteja muito claro, e só perguntar que eu esclareço.

Comment: Qual a versão do Node.js que você está utilizando? Descubra rodando `node --version` no seu terminal. Poste também o seu código completo em **forma de texto**, não imagem.

Comment: Sugiro que leia atentamente como fazer uma [boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) aqui na comunidade.

Comment: Pelo `log` do erro, o problema está na biblioteca `consign`. Você precisa postar o código completo para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Comment: To tentando arrumar a questão. Pesso desculpas pela falta de organização das perguntas, e agradeço as dicas.

Answer (score 1):

**Usando ES6**

`export default Retangulo` e depois faça `import Retangulo from "./teste.js"`
[veja mais exemplos](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)

**Usando versões anteriores**

```js
class Retangulo {
        constructor(altura, largura){
                this.altura = altura
                this.largura = largura
        }
        // . . .
}

module.exports = Retangulo;
```

```js
const Retangulo = require("./teste.js")

const a = new Retangulo(23,23)
// . . .
```

Comment: `export default` e `import` não são nativamente suportados em JS, e só irá funcionar se você estiver usando um transpiler, como `babel` ou `typescript`.

Comment: Correção ao comentário anterior: Não são nativamente suportados no Node.js, apesar de que **muito em breve** esse não será mais o caso. É importante ter em mente que JavaScript e Node.js são coisas diferentes.

Comment: atualizei a resposta, obrigado pelos comentários, tinha esquecido esse detalhe

Comment: O erro continua deu Unexpected token export, e quando eu uso o module.exports normal ele reclama que nao pode exportar sem o new: TypeError: Class constructor Retangulo cannot be invoked without 'new'

Comment: @SamuelRibeiro vc está usando algum transpilador?

Comment: O que seria isso?

Comment: um que é muito usado é o Babel, ele serve pra transformar o teu código compativel com versões anteriores do javascript que não são suportadas