# export default class e import não funcionam

Tags: javascript, node.js, classes

Estou tentando realizar o export default de uma classe em node.js, mas quando tento compilar o arquivo main.js é retornado um erro do tipo:

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:84:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:264:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:312:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:694:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:526:15)

Alguém sabe me dizer por que isso acontece?

```js
//book.js
export default class Book {
  constructor(title, author) {
    this._title = title;
    this._author = author;
  }
  get title() {
    return this._title;
  }
  set title(title) {
    this._title = title;
  }
  get author() {
    return this._author;
  }
  set author(author) {
    this._author = author;
  }
  printDescription() {
    console.log(`The book ${this._title} was written by ${this._author} `);
  }
}
```

```js
//main.js
import Book from "./book.js";

const Book01 = new Book("O nome do vento", "Patrick Rothffus");

Book01.printDescription();
```

Comment: você já tentou exportar a classa usando o module.exports e depois usando o require pra importar ela?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No caso de uma utilização experimental há duas maneiras de se fazer **import** e **export**.

A primeira maneira é criar um arquivo `package.json` na pasta atual, e logo em seguida colocar neste mesmo arquivo `{"type":"module"}`. Para executar o arquivo `.js` é só colocar:

```
$ node --experimental-modules index.js
```

no lugar do `index.js` coloque o nome do arquivo que você quer executar.

---

A segunda maneira é nos arquivos que você for executar trocar o código de importação de

```
import Book from "./book.js";
```

para

```
import Book from "./book.mjs";
```

e mudar as extensões de `.js` para `.mjs`, e então executar:

```
$ node --experimental-modules index.mjs
```

no lugar do `index.mjs` colocar o nome do arquivo que você quer executar.

---

No caso de uma utilização não experimental:

```
//book.js
class Book {
  constructor(title, author) {
    this._title = title;
    this._author = author;
  }
  get title() {
    return this._title;
  }
  set title(title) {
    this._title = title;
  }
  get author() {
    return this._author;
  }
  set author(author) {
    this._author = author;
  }
  printDescription() {
    console.log(`The book ${this._title} was written by ${this._author} `);
  }

module.exports = Book;
```

---

```
//main.js
const Book = require("./book.js")

const Book01 = new Book("O nome do vento", "Patrick Rothffus");

Book01.printDescription();
```

---

### Bibliografia:

https://thecodebarbarian.com/nodejs-12-imports

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_code_package_json_code_code_type_code_field

[Como exportar uma classe em Node?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/386264/como-exportar-uma-classe-em-node)

Comment: Na verdade, na versão 12 do node, ja é possível utializar ESM imports, dá um pouco de trabalho, mas é possível sim. confira no em https://thecodebarbarian.com/nodejs-12-imports

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário.

Comment: Agora sim, o seu ficou muito bom. Valeu, removi o que eu tinha sugerido usando mjs, pois ficaram iguais.

Comment: Ah, sim. Entendo. Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos, era isso.